# HTTP 503 responses to BeginGetResponse() create massive CPU usage

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, http

I'm sending about ~3K HTTP requests per second to some HTTP servers to use an API that my service relies on.

The requests are made asynchronously by calling BeginGetResponse().

99% of the responses are 404's, which is expected, and my code handles those responses without issue. My CPU usage stays pretty low (~5-10%)

However, sometimes the servers on the API's end start experiencing problems, and every request i make gets returned a 503 error. These are handled exactly the same way as 404's, they're ignored.

Yet with the 503's the CPU usage is huge, it stays at ~60% the entire time the 503's come in. The result is that when the API servers I'm speaking with have issues, my entire server goes down as well.

Why do 503 responses from the HTTP server cause such high CPU usage compared to 404's? Do the 503's reset the TCP connections in the connection pool?

Comment: Since you are running the requests asynchronously you might be starving the server of available work threads and the CPU usage is a direct result of the requests that are being processed. When you start to get the 503 responses how many requests are executing on the server?  Are you getting any other responses at the same time you start getting the 503 responses?

Comment: The requests are independent of the responses. Regardless of what kind of response is received, the requests are sent at a constant rate. For each request i send, i get either a 404 (99%), 200 (1%), or a 503.

The callback that handles the response handles 404's and 503's exactly the same way, in the same if statement. If response = "503" or response = "404" then return.

Comment: So are you saying the 503 responses are happening with the first batch of 3k requests?  Or is it taking a couple of seconds before they show up?  Are there entries in the HTTPError log?  Normally 503 from IIS will show up there with a reason for the entry.

Comment: I don't have any HTTP error log because i don't run the API server. Why the 503's are happening on the HTTP server's end is not under my control, or interest really. My server that does the requests can do so for hours without issue, sending millions of requests. Then when 503's start coming back instead of the normal 404's, my server's CPU explodes. I have the task manager open at all times, the moment the command line shows streams of 503 responses, the CPU usage spikes. I don't know the time difference between the request and 503 response.

Comment: Okay that makes things a little more clear. The CPU spike is on your client not the server.  If you are able to post the code that makes the requests and the code for the delegate on the EndGetResponse that would be helpful in assisting you.

Comment: my suggestion would be to write a mock web server that will offer the same API, but always return a 503.  Run this web server on another computer, and run the performance analyzing tools on your client when connecting to this server.